# What is the best way to deploy JavaFX application, create JAR and self-contained applications and native installers

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea, javafx, executable-jar

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, and I have my JavaFX application ready for deployment.
The problem is that when I generate the JAR file, it won't run, when I run it in the command line, I get an Exception, FXMLLoadException, although the project is working perfectly in my IDE.

Ant tasks end with errors, after 15 minutes of building, I really don't understand what's the problem exactly.

So my question what are the right steps to deploy a JavaFX application the right way, any tutorial or guide will be welcome.

Comment: Could you post the last few lines of your ant log? The `FXMLLoadException` sounds like your `.fxml` file is not included in your `.jar`. You might want to try unpacking the jar (`unzip jarfile.jar`) and search for your `.fxml` file. Anyway, I'm using gradle with [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) and it allows deploying to many different deploy providers.

Answer (score 30):

A Java application can be packaged in various ways. Please go through [Java Packaging Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#BABCIBAD) to find everything about it. One of the packaging is a `self-contained Java application`.

There are different ways to create these packages :

- Use the `javapackager` tools that comes with your JDK
- JavaFX Ant Tasks
- JavaFX Maven Plugin for a maven project

Self-contained application is one the ways how your application can be packaged and is platform specific. The bundle contains :

- The application package
- A private copy of the JRE

A list of available bundles can be [found here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#A1324980).

Let us check out the various tools available at our disposal and how to use them:

**JavaPackager Tool**

[JavaPackager Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html#CCHIHIIJ) is the most basic tool and helps you to compile, package, sign, and deploy your Java(FX) applications, without writing any additional scripts. The `javapackager.jar` file is located in the bin directory of the JDK installation.

The list of commands, that can be used with it is [available here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html).

**JavaFX Ant Tasks**

[JavaFX Ant Tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html#CIACDJHC) helps you package your application by just creating a `build.xml` file for your project.

A set of examples on how to use ant scripts for your project can be [found here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html#CIAEBEDD).

The list of commands that can be used for with it is [available here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CIAJGAFH).

**JavaFX Maven Plugin**

[JavaFX Maven Plugin](http://javafx-maven-plugin.github.io/) leverages the usage of packaging java application to the maven platform. You can use it to package your maven based java application by adding a plugin to the project.

This plugin IMHO, if the `easiest` to use out of the three. It is a very nicely written, easy to understand tool and has extensive documentation.

**JavaFX Gradle Plugin**

[JavaFX Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) is also from the author of the maven plugin. It has all the features that the maven plugin has, but for Gradle :)

***Further Reading :***

- [Native packaging for JavaFX](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx)
- [JavaFX packaging tools update](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7)

Comment: Thx, can you update "JavaFX Maven Plugin" the link is broken. I never used maven before and I don't get any information for noobs (like me). :-/

Comment: JavaFX Maven Plugin works great for me, and so easy to use.  just add plugin to pom, and one command e.g.   "mvn jfx:native"

Comment: Note the `javapackager` tool was deprecated and replaced by `jpackage`, see: [JEP 392: Packaging Tool](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392).

Comment: The JavaFX Maven Plugin link here is obsolete and broken and has been replaced by: [the gihub hosted openjfx javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin),

Comment: Some of the blog links in this post are also now broken.

Comment: The most comprehensive and, currently, up-to-date resource (though not truly comprehensive) for this topic is [the openfjx.io documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has an extensive guide about packaging on their website for [JavaFX 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm) and for [JavaFX 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).

If you need help for your specific problem, post the code and the stacktrace of the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven, another very smart approach is to use `maven-shade-plugin` ([link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html)). It builds one big fat jar with all dependencies inside which you can execute directly without any further things to do. You can use this in combination with `javafx-maven-plugin`. I also tried different approaches and played around a long time and this solution was the only one which really works. Additionally, it was easy to set up.

Here is what you have to add to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>your.package.name.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>your.package.name.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Change your package name inside `mainClass` for shade and also javaFx plugin and you are done. Now you can build your Application as always with `mvn package`.

Comment: The zenjava JavaFX Maven Plugin referenced here is obsolete and broken and has been replaced by: [the gihub hosted openjfx javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin),

Comment: For recent JavaFX applications (e.g. JavaFX 11+), creation of a jar using maven shade is not recommended.  JavaFX 11+ is designed to be run as part of a modular distribution, which isn't really designed to be compatible with a shaded jar.  See the [openjfx documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) for some alternate options for runtime image generation.