# App Icon not showing after build using Maven and JavaFx

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

I've been having trouble with my app's icon not showing up after I build the native installer in maven; however when I run the app within Eclipse the icon is displayed. The icon file `Icon.png` is located within the resources folder. Below is the Main class for my application, which configures the use of the icon file. Any suggestions?

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    private Parent rootLayout;
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private String title = "Cowley's Chaos Stat Parser";
    private static String log4jxml = "src/main/resources/com/sohjiro/log4j.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DOMConfigurator.configure(log4jxml);
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        try
        {
            primaryStage = stage;
            primaryStage.setTitle(title);
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Icon.png")));
            rootLayout = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Main", e);
        }
    }

    public static Logger getLogger()
    {
        return logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an eclipse way, but the naming conventions are the same, so have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31303338/4170073