# Change image from installer inno

Tags: javafx, netbeans, inno-setup

I want to change this image from installer:

[image: Installer screenshot]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try [this](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Changing-icon-in-EXE-installer-generated-by-Inno-Setup-Native-packaging-td5750444.html)

Comment: Or even better, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298015/include-icon-in-self-contained-javafx-application).