# Deployment in JavaFX 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, efxclipse

I am new in the JavaFx world and have written my first program. Now I want to deploy it. I am using Eclipse (version Mars 4.5.0) and the "e(fx)clipse - IDE" plugin (version 2.1.0.201508240705).

In the project there is a `build.fxbuild` file:

[image]

I've chosen `exe` as packaging format. When I click `Generate and build.xml and run` on the right side, only jars are created:

[image]

But I have a few further questions:
- how can I create an `exe` file (as I've chosen in the `build.fxbuild` file)
- I want to ship the jre (version 8) with it
- what external (not in Eclipse) opportunities are there for deploying a JavaFX application?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is a possibility. [This article](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) (starting at point 6.4) may also be useful for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to deploy JavaFX application, create JAR and self-contained applications and native installers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145772/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-javafx-application-create-jar-and-self-contained)

Comment: Also go through this [tutorial ...](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/)

Comment: Why isn't there a "offcical" tool from Java to build exes? How can edit the auto-build `build.xml` that the (with InnoSetup) created exe-file isn't an installer. I only want to an exe to start the program with (without installation!)

Comment: @mrbela The packaging tool included with JavaFX should enable you to create .exe files (assuming you are running on windows), and the e(fx)clipse wrapper for it that you showed should do that. You should end up with a "bundles" subdirectory of "deploy", and the .exe in there. I believe the windows packaging has a dependency on InnoSetup. Were there any error messages when you ran the builder? It may help to read through the [deployment documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/), particularly chapter 7.

Comment: @mrbela If you only looking for converting your runnable JAR to an EXE file, there is no explicit documentation for it in JavaFX documents. But you can use the many alternate solutions present - [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)