# Create one jar for javaFX in Maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am new in Maven and i am missing a point to get the whole picture regarding deployment. When i create the final java jar let's say for a desktop application to be introduced to the final user (customer), does the final user have to install maven and create a repository path to download dependancies or not?
And what is required to be done the final user can use the jar?
Should some steps be handed to make the result jar like ordinary jars without Maven?

Comment: Did you look there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145772/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-javafx-application-create-jar-and-self-contained

Comment: You can either create one jar by some jar packager tools online (or manually by unzipping) or create a self containing java application with all dependencies in the installer.