# Are there Maven plugin to create JavaFX self-contained deployment

Tags: javafx

I have a maven-based JavaFX application that's ready for deployment. I found this great article [What is the best way to deploy JavaFX application, create JAR and self-contained applications and native installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145772/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-javafx-application-create-jar-and-self-contained/30162808) on Stackoverflow that could have answered my question, however, it's dated to 2015 and the link for the article of interest has been removed. Any insights will be great.

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/

Comment: Or https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: Thanks, I will look at these links more in-depth, but by a cursory glance I didn't see any references to Maven Plugin, which I am interested in, so I can leverage the Netbeans IDE to create the deployment without the use of Jpackage. The URL that I embedded in my original post actually had a link to the Maven plugin but as I mentioned, the link no longer exists.

Comment: `jpackage` is relatively new, and I haven't yet seen a maven plugin for it (though that doesn't mean one doesn't exist somewhere). There are plugins for jlink, which would minimize the amount you needed to do outside of the IDE to build the installer package. (One way or another, though, you should use jpackage to create the native bundle, whether it's directly from the command line, through a script, or through a maven or gradle plugin.)

Comment: James_D, thanks as always