# gradle javafx intellij project to exe program

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, exe

Is there any step by step guide that explain to a new programmer how to go from a working gradle javafx project (with multiples classes, controllers, resources...) in intellij to exe / msi installer?

Any help would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to make an installer from a project that I made using javafx with gradle in intellij. You can fild the project on [github](https://github.com/dcfrenci/AppProject_Preventivo). Thanks again in advance.

Comment: See also [_Getting Started with JavaFX_](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) in the [tag:javafx] tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info); the last also has a section on deployment.

Comment: Please see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30162808/12844632

Comment: @EgorKlepikov that answer, though once good, is now obsolete and much of the information in it and resource links that it provides, no longer apply for modern JavaFX distributions.  The answer would probably confuse more than help.

Comment: Some gradle tools for building installers for JavaFX apps are the badass [runtime](https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) and [jlink](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) plugins.  Tool recommendations and requests for guides are generally off-topic for StackOverflow, so the question will probably be closed.  But you can find examples and documentation for what you attempting to do at the links provided.